# Running mysql_secure_installation on Synology 215J NAS with MariaDb and phpMyAdmin

Tags: mariadb, synology

I have a Synology 215J NAS drive running DSM 6.0. I've installed the MariaDB and phpMyAdmin packages and am able to create/edit databases etc from within phpMyAdmin. However, I've read that to secure the database I should run the mysql_secure_installation binary file. Where can I find this?? I've connected to the NAS via SSH but cannot seem to locate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Isaac points out, this script is usually installed in /usr/bin. However, what it does is not a lot of stuff, and if you're installing just one server, it's quite easy to do everything that mysql_secure_installation does manually. Here's everything the script does:

- Set a password for local root accounts (localhost, 127.0.0.1, ::1)
- Remove other root accounts (disable root logon remotely)
- Drop the "test" database
- Flush privileges (ensure the prior changes are reflected in the running server)

Comment: Good point; finding the script may be more hassle than just doing these steps manually.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_secure_installation` comes with MySQL (and, [apparently, MariaDB as well](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_secure_installation/)) and in your installation is probably in the same folder as the `mysql` executable; on my Debian system, both are in `/usr/bin/` which is consistent with most Linux platform's standards. I don't know anything about how Synology packages DSM, but most distributions should use a similar location. You could try `which mysql` to find the `mysql` executable. Your distribution may also opt to not include `mysql_secure_installation`; you should read the release notes included if you have trouble finding it.